# what is the difference between parameter and variable in ARM template?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-rm-template

what is the difference between parameter and variable in ARM template.

Answer (score 0):

A parameter value is passed in from the outside, for example by a pipeline using a [parameter file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/parameter-files). The value of a variable is defined or calculated internally.

Parameters can be used to have the template behave different according to the environment (test, prod for example). A practical example is having a values-prod.json and a values-test.json file with the environment specific values for the parameters.